# Spring-Jboss: Security debugging is enabled

Tags: spring, spring-security, log4j, jboss7.x

I have a Spring (4.1.7) MVC application running on Jboss (7.1.3). 
In the server.log, I have the following message

```
16:06:21,564 WARN  [org.springframework.security.config.debug.SecurityDebugBeanFactoryPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) 

********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************
```

I want to change the log level of spring security to INFO. 
I tried these 2 lines in my log4j.properties

```
    log4j.category.org.springframework.security = INFO
    log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO
```

but none of them works.

I also modified the config of Jboss (standalone.xml) by adding these lines

```
<logger category="org.springframework.security">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

but the message still appears in the server log.
Can you please tell me how can we change the log level of spring?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that's a warning message. If you set the level to `INFO` it will print `INFO` and higher levels.

If you don't want to see that specific message you could add a category for `org.springframework.security.config.debug.SecurityDebugBeanFactoryPostProcessor` and set it to `ERROR`. I'm not sure what other messages you'd be missing though.

Comment: Thank you James. 
Set the category of org.springframework.security to ERROR makes disappear the message. But the same thing with org.springframework.security.config.debug.SecurityDebugBeanFactoryPostProcessor does not solve the problem.

Comment: There were some significant changes with log4j integration after JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. You might want to make sure you don't have a category `org.springframework.security.config.debug` defined in any log4j configuration files or the logging subsystem.